# When does the .NET FW BitmapImage class download/cache?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, download, bitmapimage

I am a little confused as to this class, I was hoping someone could shed some light.
I know that when it downloads depends on the [BitmapCreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) of the image.

However, when you create an absolute [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), say:

```
var Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://...", UriKind.Absolute))
```

It won't download it right away, because DelayCreation is the default [BitmapCreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), correct?

What if you do:

```
var Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://...", UriKind.Absolute))
Image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
```

Will it start downloading the image immediately after you set its BitmapCreateOptions?
If so, then this has the same behavior, correct?

```
var Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://...", UriKind.Absolute)) { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None }
```

Ok, now, how does caching work for [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?

1. When does a BitmapImage get "cached"?
2. Do only downloaded e.g. "absolute" images get cached or local e.g. "relative" images as well?
3. When/how often does the cache get refreshed?
4. Does this mean that I do not need to worry about manually caching the images in Isolated Storage my Windows Phone Project?

And, finally, when do the [ImageOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.imageopened%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and [ImageFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.imagefailed%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) events get raised?

1. Do they get raised only when a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is downloaded?
2. Or do they get raised when a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is loaded from the cache?
3. Or when they get rendered on a screen?

Comment: Nobody knows how the image cache works? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is months late but for the record, the download happens when EndInit is called, any other changes to properties after this is discarded. Using constructors other than the default constructor will automatically initialize the image.

In other words:

```
var Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://...", UriKind.Absolute));
// The image is now intialized and is downloading/downloaded
Image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None; // nothing happens here
```

If you want to set a property you initialize manually like this:

```
var Image = new BitmapImage();

Image.BeginInit();
Image.UriSource = new Uri("http://...", UriKind.Absolute)
Image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None; // This is default anyway so it won't affect
// ..Setting other properties...
Image.EndInit();
```